# Find which reference dll contains a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to copy methods from one project into another project.  Some of the methods have are depenedent on referenced modules.  How can the reference that contains the method be determined short of opening all the referenced dlls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the method call and select "Go to Definition" (or the like, don't have Visual Studio open right now). The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>F12</kbd> (thanks [@seth flowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444610/seth-flowers))

That should take you the the Object Browser and let you know which assembly the method is in.

Comment: You can also type F12 if your cursor is on the method.